# AngularJs: how can I extract the variables/expressions that are defined in an template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to find a way to extract all the the variables/expressions that are defined within a template.

This is an example of the template:

```
<div> 
    first name: {{firstname}} <br/>
    last name: {{lastname}}
</div>
```

And I would like to get a list that contains:

```
firstname
lastname
```

Is there a way to do this with angulars onboard functionality?

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: Basically, if you're using a directive that holds the template, it has its own scope, the elements are accessible using the directiveScope. Maybe this will help http://juristr.com/blog/2015/01/learning-ng-directives-access-scope-controller/.

Answer (score 0):

First proof of concept will looke like that:

```
Array.prototype.map.call(angular.element($0).scope().$$watchers, function(watcher) {
  return watcher.exp.parts[1].exp // ['firstname', 'lastname']
})
```

It returns array of watchers binded to elemement ($0) with ng-scope. Next step is the way how to pass recursive all elements with ng-scope class

Comment: thx this goes into the right direction, but it is failing when I'm invoking this with an controllers scope, because parts is undefined.